# Proper way to uninstall the legacy TFS build service

Tags: tfs

The legacy TFS build service, the one that sits in the service list as "Visual Studio Team Foundation Build Service Host 2015" and does XAML builds. What's the proper way to uninstall it?

When I go to TFS Admin Console and click Unregister, the service is stopped, but remains in the system.

I can get rid of it with `sc delete`, but that's crude.

I don't see anything relevant underneath Control Panel/Uninstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a stand-alone build server, uninstall TFS entirely and if the service is still there, manually remove it. It doesn't really matter one way or the other, honestly.

If it's a combo app tier/build server, just leave it alone.

Comment: For the life of me I couldn't find it under Uninstall. What does TFS list itself as?

Comment: Never mind, found it. Listed as "Team Foundation Server" (not as Microsoft anything, not a Visual Studio anything).